# Создание таблицы умножения

Tags: javascript

```
let table=document.createElement("table");
let tr=document.createElement("tr");
let td=document.createElement("td");
document.body.append(table);
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for(let j=0;j<10;j++){
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.innerText=i*j;
    }
}
```

не добавляются на страницу новые строки и столбцы. Как это исправить?

Comment: т.к. вы создаёте 1 раз столбец и строку, если нужны новые, то нужно создавать их, непосредственно, в самом цикле

Comment: а как это сделать? не понимаю... Подскажите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста

```js
let table = document.createElement("table");

document.body.append(table);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");

  table.appendChild(tr);
  
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td.innerText = i * j;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!) А почему нельзя было создать переменные tr и td глобально?

Comment: @Domosed_007, вы создаёте их 1 раз, а нужно 81 раз

Comment: @Domosed_007, метод `appendChild` - перемещает существующий элемент в новый контейнер, соответственно, если у тебя всего один элемент, он будет переставляться на каждой итерации.